# How can I fix the error while installing opencv4nodejs?

Tags: node.js, opencv, visual-studio-code, cmake

I use visual studio code and I tried to use opencv in my project.

```
npm install opencv4nodejs

Error: 
ERR! Error: failed to execute cmake --version, cmake is required to build opencv, error is: Error: Command failed: cmake --version
'cmake'��(��) ���� �Ǵ� �ܺ� ����, ������ �� �ִ� ���α׷�, �Ǵ�
��ġ ������ �ƴմϴ�.
npm ERR! opencv-build@0.1.9 install: `node ./install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the opencv-build@0.1.9 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

I thought it was an error for cmake, but I already installed cmake(version:3.20.3)
How can I fix this problem? I use Windows.